# Check value if exists in column

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to know how to maximize speed when querying for the presence of a `varchar` value in a column in a specific table. I don't need to know where it is, or how many occurrences there are, I just want a `true`/`false`. Of course, the column has an index.

Now, I have this:

```
SELECT exists (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE column = <value> LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: For check if a column name exists, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636439/287948

Answer (score 30, accepted):

EXISTS should normally return as soon as the subquery finds one row that satisfies its WHERE clause.  So I think your query is as fast as you can make it.

I was a little surprised that `LIMIT 1` seems to always speed up the query very slightly.  I didn't expect that.  You can see the effect with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT exists (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE column = <value> LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how query is commonly used for this (check if exist with max speed)

Answer (score 2):

I have had recent success with the following in some cases:

```
SELECT count(1) > 0
FROM table
WHERE column = <value>
```

Comment: what do you mean "in some cases"?

Comment: @SafwanLjd Surprisingly using 'count(1) > 0' is faster in some cases and exists is faster in others.  In most cases 'count(1) > 0' leads to cleaner looking code.

Comment: I guess the correct query will be: ```SELECT count(1) > 0 FROM table WHERE column = <value>;```