# Checking if a value exists in a column of a database from a promisified Postgres query

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, querying

Here's my code:

```
const util = require('util')
const { Client } = require('pg');

const db = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

db.connect();

const queryP = util.promisify(db.query)

async function doStuff() {
  let inDatabase = await queryP.call(db, 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM searchtable WHERE val = $1) AS it_does_exist', [testValue]);
  console.log("In the Database: " + inDatabase);
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to return some kind of binary option (true/false) where the inDatabase is set to one thing if the 'testValue' is found in the table's 'val' column and the other thing if it isn't. I tried adapting this:

[Check value if exists in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149596/check-value-if-exists-in-column)

but I keep getting an object returned, instead of the true/false it says should be returned...thanks for any and all help!

Output of JSON.stringify() is:

```
2021-05-10T22:26:17.723899+00:00 app[web.1]: In the Database: {"command":"SELECT","rowCount":1,"oid":null,"rows":[{"it_does_exist":false}],"fields":[{"name":"it_does_exist","tableID":0,"columnID":0,"dataTypeID":16,"dataTypeSize":1,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null],"_types":{"_types":{"arrayParser":{},"builtins":{"BOOL":16,"BYTEA":17,"CHAR":18,"INT8":20,"INT2":21,"INT4":23,"REGPROC":24,"TEXT":25,"OID":26,"TID":27,"XID":28,"CID":29,"JSON":114,"XML":142,"PG_NODE_TREE":194,"SMGR":210,"PATH":602,"POLYGON":604,"CIDR":650,"FLOAT4":700,"FLOAT8":701,"ABSTIME":702,"RELTIME":703,"TINTERVAL":704,"CIRCLE":718,"MACADDR8":774,"MONEY":790,"MACADDR":829,"INET":869,"ACLITEM":1033,"BPCHAR":1042,"VARCHAR":1043,"DATE":1082,"TIME":1083,"TIMESTAMP":1114,"TIMESTAMPTZ":1184,"INTERVAL":1186,"TIMETZ":1266,"BIT":1560,"VARBIT":1562,"NUMERIC":1700,"REFCURSOR":1790,"REGPROCEDURE":2202,"REGOPER":2203,"REGOPERATOR":2204,"REGCLASS":2205,"REGTYPE":2206,"UUID":2950,"TXID_SNAPSHOT":2970,"PG_LSN":3220,"PG_NDISTINCT":3361,"PG_DEPENDENCIES":3402,"TSVECTOR":3614,"TSQUERY":3615,"GTSVECTOR":3642,"REGCONFIG":3734,"REGDICTIONARY":3769,"JSONB":3802,"REGNAMESPACE":4089,"REGROLE":4096}},"text":{},"binary":{}},"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":false}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to print `JSON.stringify(inDatabase)` and see what's returned?

Comment: @NirAlfasi So...based on the strinigified version (I put it in the question), do I access the 'it_does_exist' value with inDatabase.rows[0].it_does_exist ?

Comment: Use the SQL expression `EXISTS (/* subquery */)`. There is probably some way to have your obfuscation layer generate that.

Comment: @nickcoding2 yes, when you run a `SELECT` you get back an array of results under `inDatabase.rows`, in your case you have only one result because you check existence. Hope it helps!