# Check if a column exists in PostgreSQL table using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I searched for a long time for the answer and did the following:

(1)

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE user_name = %s" % (table_name, username)
result = conn.query(query).result()[0][0]
if result == 0:
    (do something)
```

(2)

```
query = "SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE user_name = %s" %(table_name, username)
result = conn.query(query).result()[0][0]
if result == ' ':
    (do something)
```

(3)

```
query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE user_name = %s)" %(table_name, username)
result = conn.query(query).result()[0][0]
if result == 't':
    (do something)
```

But all don't work... the error is always:

```
column "Tom" does not exist
```

Since it really doesn't exist and I just want to check if it exists. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016132/check-if-column-exists-when-there-are-multiple-tables-with-same-name-in-differen

Comment: @ronak Yes I tried..still `column "Tom" does not exist` error.....

Comment: What database connection library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quoting your strings.

You query looks like this, once it gets to PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE user_name = Tom
```

Which compares the `user_name` column against the non-existant `Tom` column.

What you want is a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE user_name = 'Tom'
```

To do this right, you should be using parameterized statements, to avoid any possibility of SQL injection. With a DBAPI module, it's a simple as:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE user_name = %s', user_name)
```

If you need the table name to be dynamic as well, then you have to construct it like this:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE user_name = %%s' % table_name
cursor.execute(query, user_name)
```

But you need to be absolutely certain that the table name is valid. Anybody who could control that variable could do absolutely anything to your database.

Comment: in my query `query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE user_name = %s" % (table_name, username)`, the table_name and username are already strings..so it is like `table_name = "information_table"`, `username = "Tom"`...

Comment: It's "like" that, or is that somehow the actual query that is being sent to the database? I strongly suspect that it is not. What do you get if you `print repr(username)` in Python?

Comment: I think this is the problem...I did make some mistakes like `username = Tom`. So Actually I changed the sentence `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE username = %s" % (table_name, username)` to `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE username = '%s'" %(table_name, username)`, and problem solved...

Answer (score 3):

```
sql = """SELECT count(*)
         FROM information_schema.columns
         WHERE table_name = '%s'
         AND column_name = '%s'
      """ % (thetable,thecolumn)
```

Comment: I tried it and it gives me the error: `column "information_table" does not exist` where information_table is my table name. I checked and this table is already created. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Always remember: [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)

```
try:
   result = conn.query(query).result()
except ProgrammingError:  # Edumacated guess based on the documentation
   # however untested so psycopg2 raises some other instead
   pass # or do_something_when_it_does_not_exist()
else:
   (do something)
```

Comment: So.. WhateverErrorPsypgRaises is the error message string? And the syntax is try: except: else: right?

Comment: well, `except Exception` is a bad habit and I don't have a postgres to test with to see what error is raised. I'll try to find it and improve my answer.

Comment: I added the try: except: else: to my code but it still gives me `column "Tom" does not exist`  error.. Any idea about how to deal with it? Thanks!